# Alter code to when scrolled to the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

trying to adjust my code to work when the user reaches the bottom of the content as opposed to the top. currently works fine, but from the top.

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 150;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
  if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
       $('.button').addClass('shrink');
       $('.brand').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('.button').removeClass('shrink');
        $('.brand').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

function getCurrentScroll() {
  return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
});
</script>
```

I want it to function as it does, but when the user reaches 150px from the bottom, not from the top

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for

Comment: adjusted my question, It works when user scrolls from the top 150px, I want it to work 150 px from the bottom

Comment: Still extremely unclear. What do you want to animate?

Comment: Can you recreate your currently working sample in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: My apologies, by 'animate' I mean apply the class 'shrink' to the button and brand class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

To get/detect distance scrolled from top in jquery.

If you want to **GET** distance from the bottom.

I suggest using:

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
$( window ).height();

// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();
```

Getting Distance:

```
distance = parseInt($(document).height()) - parseInt(getCurrentScroll());
```

[Test code here](https://jsfiddle.net/s50n5amx/)

Your **$(window).scroll(function(){...});** is correct!

You just need to update the function **getCurrentScroll()**

```
//use:
return $(document).scrollTop();

//instead of:    
return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Then choose either **$(window).height()** or **$(document).height()**:

```
 distance = parseInt($(document).height()) - parseInt(getCurrentScroll());     
 if ( distance >= shrinkHeader ) {
    // do the adding or removing of class ....
 }
```

Do the ***adjustments*** of checking distance based on the result you want to get.

Comment: prob is I want it to detect distance from the bottom

Comment: so i just change  $(window).scroll(function() { to the last line?

Comment: I apologize, I understand the first part, but not sure what all needs replacing with distance = ... Do I replace everything from var shrinkHeader = 150; or do I keep some of that

Comment: Hi @user3550879, please see the distance value using console.log while scrolling (from that, you can adjust the var shrinkHeader = 150; and the function that check wheather you need to add or remove class).